# C++ convert 2d bitmap into 3D use C++ and OPENGL library

Tags: c++, image, opengl

I need to display a 3D image (it's a heart) in my C++ application with OPENGL library. I have got a few 2D cut hearts images. First I import those images into my project. But I don't know what to do next.

These are my images

[image]

[image]

Comment: Without any depth information you can never turn a 2d-image into a 3d-image, as you miss the crucial third dimension. The most you can do is create a simple cube with the images as textures.

Comment: Thank for your comment. I found boundaries of regions in pictures(edge detection), put the coordinates in Vector (X and Y), and then draw GL_points for each pictures on different Z axis. I created a skeleton of image, but it is not a 3d object.

Comment: And next, i'll stack them.... i don't think my algorithm is correct

Comment: Oh I see, are these just sample pictures? Do you have in fact a bunch of images that you want to represent as slices in the z axis, and construct a 3D mesh by connecting the vertex points generated form each slice image?

Comment: yes!!! WearyWanderer... exactly i must do my project like that. but i don't know to find the source or algorithm.

Comment: I think it would be better to use specialized libs for it.  Take a look at VTK http://www.vtk.org/ , and ITK - Segmentation & Registration Toolkit http://www.itk.org/  .

Comment: Thank you very much Andrey smorodov, i'll take a look on link you send me.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to understand, and this is among the most important one for OpenGL newbies is: OpenGL just draws points, lines and triangles and that's it. It's not a magical graphics library. The downside of this is, that it takes some effort to get results. The upside is, that you're only limited by your creativity.

Now in your case what you have are tomograms (slice images) any by the looks of it, these are sonography (ultrasound) images. Such images are essentially representation of "density" per position and define volume data. OpenGL by itself doesn't "know" what to make out of that. There is a 3D image format, but when drawing triangles, these will just "slice" through this.

But (and this is an important "but") you can give OpenGL programs, called "shaders" that tell it where to place what it draws and what colour to give it. And it is in this programs, that you can implement a volume raycaster which can turn this kind of image stack into a nice view.

However describing how to implement such a raycaster from scratch, zero OpenGL knowledge to actual pictures is simply outside the scope of StackOverflow; it's simply to broad. There are several tutorials around with mixed quality and results (some open source)

To give you an idea: The volume raycaster library I maintain consists of about 2500 lines of code, to cover various OpenGL version profiles and GPU capabilities (the majority in shader code generation to match the target profile). If you limit yourself to a specific set of OpenGL caps it would probably take about 1000 lines of code.

Comment: Thank you very much for responses darewolf.  I still wish I could make it using OpenGl. I also found a short tutorial using that Lib http://www.icare3d.org/codes-and-projects/codes/opengl_geometry_shader_marching_cubes.html … I'll try to understand it, but for sure i will have other questions.

Comment: @AnhNguyen: Marching Cube (or Marching Tetraedra) are a method to extract surfaces from density images. From experience I can tell you that for images like the one you have there it's an approach that hardly ever produces good images. Instead you should just implement a direct volume renderer (volume rasterizer); the images produced by such are much nicer and have higher fidelity when confronted with input data like yours. Here's a nice page describing how to do it with GLSL (the OpenGL shader language): http://www.cabiatl.com/mricro/raycast/